# No parameterless constructor, structuremap, mysql and so on

Tags: c#, mysql, ef-code-first, asp.net-identity

I'm using EF Code first(3layer: Domain,Data and Service) with VS2013 and MySQL Database and its connector to .NET.I'm also using Identity. I Enable Migration, add migration and create db, after that running project at the first I got no error and the insert or update to database are working exactly true.The problem is when I changing a line of "CODE" even make a comment I got the "No parameterless constructor" error and I'm very confuse to find where is the problem.
Some important sections of my code are here:

// base context

```
 [DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
    public class BaseContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>, IUnitOfWork
    {
       // implementations
     }
```

// main context

```
public class MainDbContext : BaseContext
    {

        public MainDbContext()
            : base()
        {
            Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        } 

//some db set
}
```

The amazing point is when I change my database from MySQL to SQL Server , I didn't any error even "no parameterless..." .
Thanks in advance.

**Edited**:

```
 public class HomeController : BaseController
    {  
        public HomeController(IUnitOfWork workContext, IUserService userService)
            : base(workContext, userService)
        {

        }
}
```

and :

```
 public class BaseController : Controller
{        
        protected IUnitOfWork _workContext;
        IUserService _userService;
        public BaseController(IUnitOfWork workContext,IUserService userService)
        {
            _workContext = workContext;
            _userService = userService;
        }
}
```

Comment: please share your codes

Comment: @Rabolf excuse me, I was wrong and now I added my code.

Comment: what class is required to have parameterless constructor? EF model do need a constructor with no parameters. Are all your models have that?

Comment: @trailmax thanks for your attention. The home controller got error. all controller have constructor that has two parameter. Now I edit the post and you will see that.

Comment: You need to tell MVC framework to use StructureMap to create controllers, otherwise your controllers are not getting injected with your service classes.